# How the code travels

Tags: books

Looking for a book that describes the path the code takes from high-level to compiler to memory etc.

Doesn't matter which programming language is used, just would really like a nice breakdown of the steps the computer takes to execute it in thorough detail.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the path "from high-level compiler to memory". Anything that is stored on a computer is stored either in memory, on disc or both. So when the compiler is producing code, that code is produced into memory: there's nowhere else it can be, until it's written to disc.

Comment: This is too broad; any book about compilers is an answer.

Comment: maybe also books on logic design and computer architecture will help